# javascript query selector won't toggle css setting on button click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to toggle CSS states to reveal a menu on clicking an animated hamburger button. For some reason, my script won't toggle transform: translateX from 0 to 100% for the nav.

Have tried onClick as well as event listeners. Am I missing something very obvious?

```js
const navSlide = () => {
    const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
    const nav = document.querySelector('.nav-links');

    burger.addEventListener('click', () => {
        nav.classList.toggle('.nav-active');
    })
}

navSlide();
```

```css
.nav-links{
position: absolute;
right: 0px;
height: 92vh;
top: 8vh;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: center;
width: 50%;
transform: translateX(100%);
transition: transform 0.5 ease-in;
}

.nav-active {
    transform: translateX(0%);
}
```

```html
<button class="burger" id="burger" onClick="navSlide()">
   <div class="burgerdiv"></div>
   <div class="burgerdiv"></div>
   <div class="burgerdiv"></div>
</button>
```

On clicking on the burger button the nav transform state should toggle to reveal the menu. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have made a typo, replace `nav.classList.toggle('.nav-active');` with `nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');` (No dot before the class)

Comment: Thanks a bunch, that's sorted the original problem but there's still an error. The button needs to be clicked twice to show the menu, is this the same issue or should I start a new thread?